# Non-destructive overlay with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, overlay

Is it possible to draw a non-destructive overlay over an image using OpenCV (I mean that does not modify the image and is merely drawn after the image has been displayed) ?

Comment: No, just make a copy of your original image, render the overlay into that and display the result.

Comment: @DanMašek: yep, makes sense.

Comment: @DanMašek: you can turn your comment to an answer, I used this solution.